# Python PyQt4 how to detect control press + mouse Scroll

Tags: python, events, pyqt, pyqt4, mousewheel

I am developing an app.I would like there to be an option to zoom in and out. to do this I would like to have the program get when the control key is clicked and the mouse is being scrolled at the same time, and zoom accordingly(scroll up for zoom in, and scroll down for zoom out) I've been doing a lot of searching and reading,but only found ways to get a control press and a mouse **click-event**,  not a mouse **scroll-event**. I also found a way to get a mouse scroll but couldn't get it to work with just control press. - and to ignore all other presses.

Could anyone suggest something to help me???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends a bit on the structure of your application.
One way to get scroll-events is to add a `wheelEvent` handler to your Widget

```
def wheelEvent(self, QWheelEvent):
    modifiers = QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
    if modifiers == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
        # do your processing
```

Another approach could be to install an eventFilter in the component where you want to intercept the scroll-events by

```
component.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
```

(maybe you have to install the event filter on the component itself iso on the viewport).

and `self` has an `eventFilter` function like

```
 def eventFilter(self, qobject, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel) :
            modifiers = QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
            if modifiers == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
                #do some scaling stuff
                return True
            return False
        else:
            # standard event processing
            return False
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but how could I know if the wheel event is scroll up or down?

Comment: the sign of event.delta() (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwheelevent.html)

Comment: which approach are you using? The wheelEvent handler or the eventFilter? With the former approach (and with the second one when the event filter is not installed correctly), it can happen that you only receive scroll-up events when at the top of your view and scroll-down events when you are at the bottom of your view.  Can you confirm this behavior? Can you also indicate the type of your component and whether or not you are installing the event filter on the viewport?

Comment: Here is my code:
`def wheelEvent(self, event):

        modifiers = QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers();

        if modifiers == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
            # here I zoom in;
        else:

            super(MainWindow, self).wheelEvent(event);

`

Comment: On which object did you define this function? and which (scrollable) views does it contain?  Probably there is a scrollable container inside that is consuming the scroll-down events.  If so, you'll have to switch to the second approach (using eventFilter)

Comment: I used this event handler on my QMainWindow. my QScrollArea is my central widget.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133564/discussion-between-cheyn-shmuel-and-marc-van-daele).